# cross compiling application for raspbian weezy

Tags: qt4, raspberry-pi

I want to compile a *qt application* on my *Ubuntu pc* and make it run on *raspberry pi*

but

**I don't want to install qt on raspberry.**

so anyone can suggest simple procedure to set up qt to cross compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install qt on your raspberry pi then you have to build qt for arm in your Ubuntu PC by passing the static option during configure

```
./configure -static <remaining options>
```

Now you can compile your qt application with static option and run it in your raspberry pi without installing qt

Comment: thank you for replay... I came to know that to cross compile Qt I will need a cross compiler which I already have.so can you please refer me link to Cross compile Qt4.

Comment: There are newer version of Qt are you sure you want to build an alder version?

Comment: have you had a chance to look at these links                                                        (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/51327-Trouble-building-Qt-Embedded-4-8-3-using-ARM-Toolchain) (https://forum.qt.io/topic/20508/qt4-on-raspberry-pi)